# Apply function with two arguments on same list and output only lower/upper triangular matrix without diagonal

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, list-comprehension, apply

I want to compare strings without unecessary comparisons, so far I have:

`[[[dice_coefficient(x,y) for x in ['a','a','b'][j]] for y in ['a','a','b'][0:j]] for j in [1,2]]`

where `dice_coefficient` is defined [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Dice%27s_coefficient#Python)

which gives the expected output but look like it would be the right approach if those strings were the comments of an author in a column of a pandas dataframe.

Comment: What is your question? What does "unnecessary comparisons" mean? Why it is not scalable?

Comment: I think there must be a better way than what I am currently doing. By unnecessary comparisons I mean comparing a string to itself or having redundant comparisons (the coefficients of both 1 vs 2 and 2 vs 1). I don't think it's scalable because I would ultimately like to do it for groups of ids in a dataframe.

Comment: To me it looks right (but a bit hard to read). You can add a bit of code to `dice_coefficient` to count how often it is called. You should see that it isn't called more often than necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing is that in your case first iteration of your outer loop (`for j ...`) is the subset of the second iteration. To compare things only once, you can do:

```
data = ['a', 'a', 'b']
[
    [
        dice_coefficient(x, y)
        for x in data[i:]
    ]
    for i, y in enumerate(data[:-1], start=1)
]
```

If you think that you'd have a lot of repetitive values in your `data` you can use [`lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) on `dice_coefficient` to avoid repetitive comparisons.

Comment: Thank you. I would have never thought of that. Let's say those strings are in the column of a pandas dataframe, any idea on how I could "plug" your list comprehension onto that column?

Comment: `data = df['column_name']` should work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need the [`combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) of your input:

```
from itertools import combinations

lst = ['a', 'a', 'b']

out = [dice_coefficient(*x) for x in combinations(lst, 2)]
```

Or:

```
from itertools import combinations, starmap

lst = ['a', 'a', 'b']

out = list(starmap(dice_coefficient, combinations(lst, 2)))
```

Output: `[1.0, 0.0, 0.0]`

If you want to generate the corresponding square matrix, this would be a good job for numpy:

```
from itertools import combinations
import numpy as np

lst = ['a', 'a', 'b']
n = len(lst)
out = np.full((n, n), np.nan)
out[np.triu_indices(n, k=1)] = [dice_coefficient(*x) for x in
                                combinations(lst, 2)]
```

Output:

```
      #   a   a    b
array([[nan,  1.,  0.],   # a
       [nan, nan,  0.],   # a
       [nan, nan, nan]])  # b
```